# Recursion Theorem question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recursion

I am trying to prove the following in Enderton's text 'Elements of Set Theory' (exercise 8 of chapter 4):

---

Let $f$ be a one-to-one function from $A$ into $A$, and assume that $c \in A - ran \ f$. Define $h: \omega \rightarrow A$ by recursion: $h(0) = c, h(n^{+}) = f(h(n))$. We show that $h$ is one-to-one.

---

So far, I have the following attempt but I am not sure that I am approaching this correctly.

Let $f$ be a one-to-one function from $A$ into $A$, and assume that $c \in A - ran \ f$. Define $h: \omega \rightarrow A$ by recursion: $h(0) = c, h(n^{+}) = f(h(n))$. We show that $h$ is one-to-one.

Let $S = \{n \in \omega \ |$ for every $m \in \omega$ different from $n$, $h(m) \neq h(n) \}$. We show that $S$ is inductive. As our base case, we have $h(0) \neq h(m)$ for any $m \neq 0$. This is because of the following. $h(0) = c$ and $\forall n \in \omega, (n = 0) \vee (\exists p \in \omega$ s.t. $n = p^{+}$) [Theorem 4C - p. 68]. Since for all $n^{+} \in \omega$, we have $h(n^{+}) = f(h(n)) = f(h(p^{+}))$, $c \notin ran \ f$ and so $ f(h(p^{+})) \neq c$.

Assuming $k \in S$, consider $h(k^{+}) = f(h(k))$. Since $k \in S$, we know that

$\forall n,k \in \omega,  (n \neq k) \ \implies \ (h(k) \neq h(n))$. So we have $h(k^{+}) = f(h(k)) \neq f(h(n)) = h(n^{+})$, for some $n^{+} \in \omega$, because $h(k) \neq h(n)$ and the fact that $f$ is a one-to-one function. So for any $n^{+}, k^{+} \in \omega$, ($n^{+} \neq k^{+}) \implies (h(k^{+}) \neq h(n^{+}))$ and we have  $k^{+} \in S$ making $S$ inductive.

Comment: Your definition of $S$ uses unusual notation, not defined in Enderton's book as far as I know, with two variables before the  $|$.  My best guess as to your meaning is that $S$ is intended to be a set of pairs of natural numbers. But then what does it mean to say it's inductive?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding something but the way I have defined $S$, it is the set of all naturals numbers such that the function $h$ on those numbers is injective. 

To say that the set $S$ is inductive is to say that $\emptyset \in S$ and $\forall n (n \in S \rightarrow n^{+} \in S)$ where $n^{+} = n \cup \{n\}$.

Does this help? It is possible I am still mistaken on these points but I am referring to the definition of 'Inductive Set' on page 68 of Enderton's 'Elements of Set-Theory'.

Comment: "The set of natural numbers such that the function $h$ on those numbers is injective" doesn't define a criterion for membership in the set. There might be many sets, such that $h$ is injective on each of them, yet they overlap in rather wild ways. Your "definition" of $S$ would not enable one, even knowing $h$ completely, to determine whether $17\in S$. $h$ might be injective on one set that contains $17$ and on another set that doesn't contain $17$. (The actual $h$ in the problem will be injective on all of $\omega$, but of course your definition of $S$ can't presuppose that.)

Comment: I see now what the issue is. Thanks for pointing out the error in my proof's assumption.

Can you suggest a way for me to begin proving what I need to prove? Thanks for your time Andreas.

Comment: Why don't you use, for your set $S$, a definition similar to the set $T$ on p. 77? That'll probably do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution might be to use the Well Ordering Principle.

Define $A$ as the complement of $S$ as follows: $A=\{n\in \omega \mid \exists m \in w, n\ne m \wedge h(n)=h(m)\}$. To show that $h$ is one-one, it suffices to show that $A$ is empty.

As you have shown, $0\not \in A$. Assume $A$ is non-empty, then by the Well Ordering Principle, $A$ has a non-zero smallest element $m^+$. By definition of $A$, there is a non-zero $k^+\ne m^+$, such that $h(m^+) = h(k^+)$. Since $f$ is one-one, we get $h(m) = h(k)$ where $m\ne k$, hence $m \in A$. But this contradicts the minimality of $m^+$ and so $A$ is empty.